# Python, Remove duplicates and get the max of it based on condition

Tags: python, regex

**Imagine the following as the input:**

```
anna-1
anna
anna-0
michael
anna-2
```

**And my expected output:**

```
michael
anna-2
```

> Condition:
>   we will print the string if there's no duplicates for it. Consider the duplicates always contain `-` in end and after that the total number of duplicates which we will take the max of it.

Comment: Please show code to prove you've tried solving it yourself.

Comment: Welcome Anna, usually it is advised to provide a minimal reproducible example that shows what you have tried so far. A question like yours will probably get down voted quickly.

Comment: @CorentinPane I've tried many different solution such as split and then switch to dict to get rid of duplicate but failed. that's why am waiting for someone to do it from scratch so i can understood the logic of thinking about the problem solving.

Comment: @TheFool thanks for your advise. i will work on that indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest going with **regular expressions** to split each input into a `name` sub-string and a `number` sub-string, based on the following pattern that we assume each input follows:

`<name>-<number>` or just `<name>`.

Have a look at the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) package for details and exact syntax, but this is what my

```py
pattern = "(?P<name>\w+)(?P<number>-\d*)?"
```

line does.

2. Going with a `dict` was indeed a good idea, I use a dictionary to store encountered numbers and gradually keep only the maximum value encountered for each input.
3. When I'm done analyzing each input, I parse them all again using the `.items()` method of dictionaries to print out data I want.

Here is the sample code I've come with to sum up:

```py
import re

inputs = ["anna-1", "anna", "anna-0", "michael", "anna-2"]

pattern = "(?P<name>\w+)(?P<number>-\d*)?"

maxNumbers = {} # Remembers the maximum number for each name

# Parse all inputs and split them into name and number
for item in inputs:
    result = re.match(pattern, item)
    # Extract the name
    name = result.group("name")
    # Extract the number (set to zero if there is no number)
    number = result.group("number")
    if number == None:
        number = 0
    else:
        number = int(number[1:])
    # Store the number in the dictionary
    if name not in maxNumbers:
        maxNumbers[name] = number
    else:
        maxNumbers[name] = max(maxNumbers[name], number)

# Parse all names and print their maximum number
for name, maxNumber in maxNumbers.items():
    if maxNumber == 0:
        print(name)
    else:
        print(name + "-" + str(maxNumber))
```

Note that you didn't specify how the program should react if the input is

```py
anna
anna-0
```

Should it print `anna-0` or just `anna`? But this you'll be able to fix by yourself.

Comment: it's will never be `anna-0` because it's usually be `anna` and `anna-1`

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through the list & check if the string has appeared more than once. If it hasn't, print the string.
2. For more than one occurrence,start checking from the end of the string for the maximum number. Find the index having the maximum number. (You can make another list if you want)

Answer (score 0):

another approach could be to

1. iterate over each word in the input
2. clean it up, remove the `-n` at the end, you can use `split` or `substring` for it
3. insert the word to a data structure called [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html)
4. traverse the keys in the counter

   - if the key occurrence is 1, print the string
   - else concatenate `-` + number of occurrences to the end of the key and print it

*only works if `num of occurrence = max prefix`, not in case where the input can be like

```
anna-1
anna-7001
```

in that case you can to use a regular `dict` with some logic behind the insert part

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using a diction as you attempted

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Assuming you input names into a list
l = ['anna-1', 'anna', 'anna-0', 'michael', 'anna-2']

# Place list into dictionary, with key as names
# and count as value
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
  name_cnt = i.split('-')
  if len(name_cnt) > 1:
    name, cnt = name_cnt
    d[name].append(int(cnt))
  else:
    k = name_cnt[0]  # no count
    d[k].append(-1)  # use default -1

# Show dictionary d
print(d)

# Show Desired Output
for k, cnts in d.items():
  cnt = max(cnts)
  if cnt == -1: # no versions of name
    print(k)
  else:
    print(f'{k}-{cnt}')
```

**Outputs**

*Dictionary d*

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
    {'anna': [1, -1, 0, 2], 
     'michael': [-1]})
```

*Final Result*

```
anna-2
michael
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage a `defaultdict` in combination with a dict comprehension:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# data in question
data = """
anna-1
anna
anna-0
michael
anna-2"""

# defaultdict
dict_ = defaultdict(int)

dict_ = {name: (number if dict_[name] <= number else dict_[name])
          for line in data.split("\n") if line
          for name, duplicate in [line.split("-") if "-" in line else (line, 0)]
          for number in [int(duplicate)]}

print(dict_)
```